asp.Net page using Python requests
I know this has been posted before, but I tried some of the solutions found but to no avail.
I am trying a login into my University Website to scrape some data behind it. Until now I only had success with Selenium but didn't really wanted to use it since it's to be implemented in another script and using requests is more viable in this specific situation.
From what I've learned the I could use a get then BeautifulSoup to grab all the input fields in the form to then fill my data in the requests.session.post(). I checked the Request Headers, and the payload from Developer tools has below:
REQUEST HEADERS
headers = {     "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36",
                "Accept" : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
                "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
                "Accept-Language" : "pt-PT,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es-US;q=0.6,es;q=0.5",
                "Cache-Control":"max-age=0",
                "Connection":"keep-alive",
                "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

Payload
payload = {
    "__LASTFOCUS": None,
    "__VIEWSTATE": "longstring",
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": "9F67D0FB",
    "__SCROLLPOSITIONX": "0",
    "__SCROLLPOSITIONY": "0",
    "__EVENTTARGET": None,
    "__EVENTARGUMENT": None,
    "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderMain%24txtLoginISEP": "username",
    "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolderMain%24txtPasswordISEP": "password",
    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$btLoginISEP":""
}

After doing all this I still get status code 302 which redirects to /error/ErrorPage.aspx?id=5787287, but to my knowledge should be /Workspace.aspx.
All the inputs in the form are:
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJMjgwNDU0NDQzD2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgEPZBYGZg8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWcWCgIBDxYCHgNzcmMFQS9nbG9iYWwvaW1hZ2VzL2ludHJhbmV0L1BhZ2luYUluaWNpYWwvaTFfYmFycmFfdG9wb19pc2VwXzIwMjMucG5nZAIDDxYCHwEFOy9nbG9iYWwvaW1hZ2VzL2ludHJhbmV0L1BhZ2luYUluaWNpYWwvaTNfbG9nb19pc2VwXzIwMjMucG5nZAIFD2QWCAIBDxYCHwEFOy9nbG9iYWwvaW1hZ2VzL2ludHJhbmV0L1BhZ2luYUluaWNpYWwvaTJfYmVtLXZpbmRvXzIwMjEuanBnZAIDDw8WBB4IQ3NzQ2xhc3MFB1RleHRCb3geBF8hU0ICAmRkAgUPDxYEHwIFB1RleHRCb3gfAwICZGQCCw8WAh8AZ2QCBw8WAh8BBT8vZ2xvYmFsL2ltYWdlcy9pbnRyYW5ldC9QYWdpbmFJbmljaWFsL2k0X3NlbG9fZW50cmFkYXNfMjAyMi5wbmdkAgkPFgIfAQVCL2dsb2JhbC9pbWFnZXMvaW50cmFuZXQvUGFnaW5hSW5pY2lhbC9pNV9iYXJyYV9mdW5kb19pc2VwXzIwMjMucG5nZAIBDxYCHwBoZAICDxYCHwBoZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAQUoY3RsMDAkQ29udGVudFBsYWNlSG9sZGVyTWFpbiRidExvZ2luSVNFUA+aG0Q0q+ieRovqjfaBebNigtc2xzOPJmX7ygQS4ljU">
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="9F67D0FB">
    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
</div>

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$txtLoginISEP" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_txtLoginISEP" class="TextBox" placeholder="UTILIZADOR" style="height: 20px; width: 187px; border-radius: 4px; padding-left: 8px;">
                                            </td>

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$txtPasswordISEP" type="password" id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_txtPasswordISEP" class="TextBox" placeholder="PALAVRA-PASSE" style="height: 20px; width: 187px; border-radius: 4px; padding-left: 8px;">
                                            </td>

<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$btLoginISEP" id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_btLoginISEP" src="/intranet/App_Themes/ISEP/layout/bt/ISEP_ENTRADAS_BT_entrar.png">
                                                        </td>

I even tried copying the payload completely from developer tools with the requests and still no correct result. I feel like there is something I'm not overlooking and making me frustrated.
Is the only solution use of Selenium?
Appreciate any feedback on the matter.
